# How do I force Microsoft Office 365 to use my system color settings when it refuses to?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Since my primary computer is currently down, I'm using my laptop. They are both using Microsoft Office 365.

I'm using Word documents and trying to get the document title bar to use my system color setting (purple) rather than the blue that it insists on.

I have the Office Theme setting on "Use system setting" but it still is stuck on that Word blue. The other drop down options seem to work, but I can't figure out how to make this one work. I am almost certain it was working fine on my other computer (hence the reason it's bugging me that I can't get it to work on this one), though maybe I was mistaken and there is just something else that is throwing me off on it.

Any help would be appreciated.